# anchors and input fields not working in IE11

Tags: html, input, hyperlink, internet-explorer-11

This issue only exists in IE11. In all other browsers and versions of IE, everything is fine. The issue is that both links and input fields do not work in IE11. Here is a link to the site I'm talking about: http://singleatl.com

When you hover over a link nothing happens, a click does nothing. You can not type in form fields. There are no other elements blocking the fields and no strange CSS markup. This happens to every anchor element and input element on the page. It is not specific to the nav. The anchors are coded like so:

```
<li><a href="atlanta-matchmaker-testimonials.html" >Testimonials</a></li>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: According to IE's devtools, you have a stray `</ul>` in your `<section class="front hm1">`.  Run your page past the W3 validator (http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure there aren't any more HTML errors.

Comment: Hi, I removed that closing ul but no luck everything still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page works fine when IE11 is in IE10 emulation mode, and when you remove the `z-index: -9999` from the `body` element set by `main.css`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676600/ie11-negative-z-index

Comment: I would have never thought of that. Works PERFECTLY thank you